# SQLite: reuse quoted alias

Tags: sql, sqlite, quote

I'd like to reuse an alias that contains a non-alphabetic character in a query, something like:

```
 SELECT 42 AS "the#answer", "the#answer"+8 AS "fifty";
```

Output I want: `42|50`; output I get: `42|8`.

I've tried almost every possible combination of quote types, and looked for documentation, but I can't seem to find a working solution.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL *cannot* refer to an alias from the same output clause in which it was introduced. (It has nothing to do with quoting, which only allows otherwise invalid identifiers; some SQL vendors would have thrown an error, but SQLite appears "more relaxed" in the handling of this case.)

You *could* use a nested query ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/25e1a/3)).

```
SELECT fortytwo, fortytwo + 8 as fifty
FROM (
    SELECT 42 AS fortytwo)
```

This works because the referenced identifier, `fortytwo`, was introduced in a *"previous"* output clause.